# Фантомный отступ на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mobile

На сайте [одной фирмы][1] решили отказаться от мобильной версии (не спрашивайте, почему). После этого при входе на сайт с мобильного телефона справа появляется отступ. Специально для этих целей я вставил на страничку блок для проверки ширины элементов, но он ничего не выдал путного. Блок называется `.what-target`, а сайт выкидывает алерт, если находит блок больше 980px при таче на элемент.
Вопрос: как убрать отступ на мобилке? Скриншоты Asus Zenfone 2, iPhone6

[1]: http://rostbild.ru/[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: samsung a3, lenovo a316 i , iphone 5s нету дефектов (на других не проверял)... для решения конкретной задачи принято показывать проблему ...исправьте вопрос таким способом что бы было видно предмет вопроса

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, добавил. Видите справа есть небольшой отступ?

Comment: Не воспроизводится. Да и тут решают более конкретные задачи, чем "найди у меня на сайте".

Comment: @Other, тут конкретная задача. Отступ справа на мобильнике. Скриншот прилагается

Comment: я не вижу... вопрос следует закрыть ...

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, посмотрите, где заканчивается панель браузера и где заканчивается баннер. между ними есть отступ

Comment: я смотрел (перечислил с каких устройств) и не увидел ни каких отступов

Comment: @ЕгорЖолнин, Нет, не конкретная. Тут надо перебирать, отлаживать. Вместо "как?" - "так!". Плюс - ни у кого не воспроизводится отступ.

Comment: @Other Asus, iPhone6

Comment: @ЕгорЖолнин, На шестёрке бага не вижу, а Asus'а нет под рукой.

Comment: @Other, все выяснилось. Лечится обновлением браузера. Но что делать со старыми версиями...

Comment: Это извечный вопрос. В современности решается детектом и выдачей старым браузерам полифиллов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил костыльно, потому что в новых версиях браузеров такого нет.

```
.all-outer-wrappers-had-100%-width {width: 100vh}
```